# use Jsonreader setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON error

Tags: java, android, gson

I try to solve this error but I can't.

Main activity code

```
public class Reservation_main extends AppCompatActivity {
final String TAG = "ReservationMainActivity";
public static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:81/PhpProject1/room.php";
RecyclerView recycle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reserve_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recycle = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recycle.setLayoutManager(manager);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response);

                    ArrayList<Reservation_room_list> roomList = new JsonConverter<Reservation_room_list>()
                            .toArrayList(response, Reservation_room_list.class);

                    Reservation_room_adapter adapter = new Reservation_room_adapter(getApplicationContext(), roomList);

                    recycle.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}
}
```

Room adapter

```
public class Reservation_room_adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Reservation_room_adapter.RoomViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Reservation_room_list> room;

public Reservation_room_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Reservation_room_list> room){
    this.context = context;
    this.room = room;
}

@Override
public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int type){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_reserve_layout, parent, false);

    RoomViewHolder roomViewHolder = new RoomViewHolder(view);
    return roomViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (RoomViewHolder holder, int position){
    Reservation_room_list rooms = room.get(position);
    holder.roomNo.setText(rooms.roomid);
    holder.price.setText("" + rooms.price);
    holder.roomDescription.setText(rooms.type);

    String fullUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:81/PhpProject1/" + rooms.image;

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(fullUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.bed_room_web)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(holder.roomImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    if (room != null){
        return room.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CardView info;
    public TextView roomNo;
    public TextView roomDescription;
    public TextView price;
    public ImageView roomImage;

    public RoomViewHolder(View roomView){
        super(roomView);
        info = (CardView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.view);
        roomNo = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.room);
        roomDescription = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.details);
        price = (TextView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        roomImage = (ImageView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }
}

}
```

This is the room_list code

```
public class Reservation_room_list implements Serializable{
public String type;
public String image;
public String status;
public int roomid;
public int capacity;
public double price;
}
```

php code

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
  require 'index.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `room` WHERE Status = 'available' ORDER BY 
  Room_number desc";
  $response["sucsess"] = false;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $response["success"] = true;
        $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

MySingleton code

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = 
    Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

Error I get when run

> 09-03 07:45:34.436 6020-6020/fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   09-03 07:45:34.465 6020-6020/fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2 D/ReservationMainActivity: [{"Room_number":"1","Type":"luxury","Capacity":"10","Status":"available","Price":"1000","Image":"img/hotel-bedroom-decor-hotel-style-bedrooms.jpg"}]/* 
>                                                                                           * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
>                                                                                           * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
>                                                                                           * and open the template in the editor.
>                                                                                           */
>   09-03 07:45:34.504 6020-6020/fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   09-03 07:45:34.504 6020-6020/fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2, PID: 6020
>                                                                                 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 151
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:779)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>                                                                                     at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42)
>                                                                                     at fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2.Reservation_main$1.onResponse(Reservation_main.java:53)
>                                                                                     at fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2.Reservation_main$1.onResponse(Reservation_main.java:44)
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                                  Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 151
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1336)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:527)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:775)
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769) 
>                                                                                     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
>                                                                                     at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42) 
>                                                                                     at fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2.Reservation_main$1.onResponse(Reservation_main.java:53) 
>                                                                                     at fyp.hotelreservationsystemver2.Reservation_main$1.onResponse(Reservation_main.java:44) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

The gson and JSONconverter I use:

```
[1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9c7Ta0Lo2OVVkkyU1RJVzQ5bTQ
```

Comment: post your json string

Comment: I would suggest 1) opening a web browser and going to the room.php page 2) Setting the response to only a TextView and just looking at it. If it looks like JSON, then parse it

Answer (score 0):

> [{"Room_number":"1","Type":"luxury","Capacity":"10","Status":"available","Price":"1000","Image":"img/hotel-bedroom-decor-hotel-style-bedrooms.jpg"}]/* * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates * and open the template in the editor. */

Seems to be the response, to put it simply the comment block that is somehow appended to the response makes the response not valid json. Since the text does not appear in the given code it must originate from elsewhere in your application. Since the response is faulty the error must be in the PHP code.